# Retrieve text from database and format it on the front end of the website

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008-r2

I have some text currently stored in my database table as nvarchar. 
  I am currently retrieving the text using a stored procedure and binding it to  a literal within a gridview on the front end.

What I would like to do is to retrieve the text and then format it , like inserting line spaces and making 
  certain area bold. Is it possible to do so ? Can anyone give me an idea of how it can be done ?

One idea thats striking me is to use XML while storing the text . But even if I do that how would I make a certain part of the text bold and include line spaces.

So currently, my text is stored in the database table column nvarchar(max) as:

```
This is the heading this is the content
```

What I would like to do is to display the above within a gridview like:

```
**This is a Heading** (heading in bold)
 This is the content
```

Comment: Do you have to work with one string could you not split the returned string into seperate heading and content strings?

Comment: A _really_ cool way to do this, could be inserting the text in the database as html...

Comment: My 2c: I wouldn't store it as HTML in the database as you'll invariably wish to use it in a context which *doesn't* want HTML and you'll need to strip it.

Comment: @Plymouth223 - how would you handle it?  SqlSamurai could store the html and non-html values in separate fields, but that would require syncing the two on change of either.

Comment: @davids I'd store as XML and use an XSLT to transform it meaning you can natively parse it in SQL and .NET

Comment: The only purpose to use the text would be to display it on the website, so I can store it as html within the database.But I am binding the text to a literal within an asp.net gridview, so How would I get the html and bind it to the literal ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method (one I have used several times) is to store the html in the table like this:

```
<h1>This is the heading</h1>This is the content
```

You will have to add special handling for working with html, but it works just fine.

You can also store the header string in one field, and body in another.

Short of that, you would have to have some indicator telling the front which part of the string should be bolded, etc. and that can get very complex

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that this is possible but takes some work.

You first need to decide in what format are you going to store the data and how can you specify format on the client side, before text is entered into database.

If you have WYSIWYG editor for text – html conversion you can try storing the HTML. This will be the easiest way in terms of storage.

If you decide to use this method note that you’ll need to do a lot of validation on the server to avoid cross site scripting attacks. Shortly put – make sure the HTML you get on the server doesn’t contain any javascript or any tags apart from those you want to support.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use Editor of AJAX Toolkit, doesnt required any other thing, its a complete editor, you can even color your font as u wanted.